# Как подключить готовую функцию autocomplite в opencart?

Tags: ajax, cms, opencart

Недавно устроился на работу по cms opencart и возникло пару вопросов с подключением модулей! Но тут я хотел бы узнать именно за подключение автокомплита и что я делаю не так... В общем ребят вопрос распишу очень подробно и со скринами!
1)ctrl+c => ctrl+v функцию автокомплита готовую из opencart в .tpl файл, результат моих действий ниже
а)joxi.ru/Drlb3XnCJD9Z2P тут показывает поле с автокомплитом (аяксом ) ,до ввода символов в поле
б)joxi.ru/1A5XkB4tZY9Z2E тут показывает поле с автокомплитом (аяксом ) ,после ввода символов в поле , т.е. класс изменился и по идее он должен поменяться назад после подгрузки ключевых слов, но чуда не происходит поэтому поле не возвращается в исходное положение
в)joxi.ru/ZrJdo9DtN8qj2j
тот же файл JS функция
г)joxi.ru/LmG5oBxhpGQ3Al
2)Не буду говорить ,что в language все добавил и ошибок ни каких нет! так же в контроллер добавил следующее
а)joxi.ru/bmo0X1pCjeRN2y
б)joxi.ru/J2bDQW7tvbj3r6
3)Естественно контроллер данного файла , т.е. controller/module/carousel.php 
Хочу сказать ,что я делал данный автокомплит и он каким-то чудесным образом заработал... но что-то в дальнейшем пошло не так и я все удалил и переделал по-другому... и все опять не работает! Т.е. Я хотел бы узнать как и что нужно делать спасибо огромное тем кто хотя бы дочитал до сюда!
Я так думаю ,что проблема заключается в том ,что я не знаю как правильно вытащить данные слова-подсказки из БД , т.е. модель у меня ни где по-сути не подключена...